# Undefined Variable : key on tabelstok.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, database, xampp, localhost

before i got this problem, i was try to connect the database from laravel to phpmyadmin and i think it's solved i don't know if it solved or not yet cause the error said different before it says "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" something like that and after i change a little codes and i got another problem.

i got an error messages like **Undefined Variable: Key** from this file name **tabelstok.blade.php**

codes from **tabelstok.blade.php** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tabelstok</title>
    <h1> Tabel Stok Master </h1>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="80%" border="1">
        <th> No </th>
        <th> Kode Barang </th>
        <th> Nama Barang </th>
        <th> Harga Barang Terakhir </th>
        <th> Id Satuan </th>

        <?php
        foreach ($ds as $key) {

        }
        ?>

        <tr>
        <td> {{$key->no}} </td>
        <td> {{$key->kode}} </td>
        <td> {{$key->nama}} </td>
        <td> {{$key->hbt}} </td>
        <td> {{$key->ids}} </td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Controller codes :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class regbcontroller extends BaseController     
{
    //class terdiri dari :
    //1. fungsi/method + atribut/data/variabel
public function fungsimenuregb(){
    return view ('regb.viewcontroller');
    }

public function fungsimenuregb2(){
    return view ('regb.viewcontroller2');
    }

public function fungsimenuparam(Request $r){
    $nil1=$r->nilai1;
    $nil2=$r->nilai2;

        return view ('regb.viewparam')
        ->with('nilaa1', $nil1)
        ->with('nilaa2', $nil2)
        ;
    }

    public function fungsitabelstok(Request $r){
        $ds=DB::table('tbbarang')
                 ->get();

        return view ('regb.tabelstok')
                 ->with('ds',$ds);

    }

public function simpantambahstok(Request $r){
    //proses simpan
    $simpan=array
    (
            'kode' => $r -> kd,
            'nama' => $r -> nama,
            'hbt' => $r -> hbt,
            'idsatuan' => $r -> ids
    );

    DB::table ('tbbarang') ->insertgetID($simpan);

    return redirect('tabelstok')
        -> with('pesan', 'profile updateSuccess');
}

}
```

and this is my Route codes :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


//UNTUK MEMANGGIL WELCOME
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



//UNTUK MENERIMA REQUEST MENUSATU
Route::get('/menusatu', function () {
    return view('regb.halamansatu');
});

Route::get('/menudua', function () {
    return view('regb.halamandua');
});

    
Route::get('/menukontroller','regbcontroller@fungsimenuregb');

Route::get('/menukontroller2','regbcontroller@fungsimenuregb2');

Route::get('/menu/{nilai1}/{nilai2}','regbcontroller@fungsimenuparam');

Route::get('/tabelstok','regbcontroller@fungsitabelstok');

Route::get('/tambahstok','regbcontroller@formtambahstok');

Route::get('/editstok', 'regbcontroller@formeditstok');

Route::post('/simpantambahstok', 'regbcontroller@simpantambahstok');

Route::post('/simpaneditstok', 'regbcontroller@simpaneditstok');
```

i don't understand. please help

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if that `foreach` loop never runs (there is nothing to iterate), then there is no variable named `$key` created ... also you shouldn't be expecting to use a variable created in a loop like that outside the loop ... that whole section from `<tr>` to `</tr>` should be inside the loop .... also this isn't valid HTML structure

Comment: fyi, Blade has its own [foreach()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)

Comment: try to put if before foreach loop and check wheather $ds exists. Then if yes you can put it in foreach loop but like lagbox mentioned

Comment: @lagbox oh god, i thought it was from my controller file, i found a typos before and it solved and then i got this problem. and just simple like that. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution from @lagbox's comment. I tried to put the whole `<tr>` to `</tr>` inside the loop like he said and it works.

Comment: Hi, please make a [comunity wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) from @lagbox's comment and mark it as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

You are not in foreach loop. Your `$key` variable is out of loop ;)